# How to use computeDistanceBetween() correctly?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, google-maps-api-3, distance, anonymous-function

I am newbie in Maps API, i am trying get the distance (in Km) from 2 adress. What is wrong with this code?

```
var mygc = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var locationOrigem;
var locationDestino;

var latOrigem  = 0;
var longOrigem = 0;

var latDestino  = 0;
var longDestino = 0;


mygc.geocode({'address' : 'Presidente Vargas 897, Centro RJ'}, function(results, status){

    locationOrigem = results[0].geometry.location;
    latOrigem   = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    longOrigem  = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

});

mygc.geocode({'address' : 'Abelardo Bueno 3000, Barra da Tijuca RJ'}, function(results, status){

    locationDestino = results[0].geometry.location;
    latDestino  = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    longDestino = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

});

alert(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(locationOrigem, locationDestino));
```

By a unknown reason, var **locationOrigem and locationDestino** are "undefined" outside of anonymous functions ??? Why???

Comment: See my updated post. Does it work for you now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you included this script?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
```

What happen when you run your code? Are you sure that your addresses were geocoded correctly? Are you sure that problem is in `computeDistanceBetween`. Try to dump all variables.

**UPDATE:**

Requests to the Geocoder are executed asynchronously. So request for distance calculation were run before you had got geocoded data. That is why your variables were `undefined`. You need to use callbacks to ensure that request is finished. Try this code

```
var mygc = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var locationOrigem;
var locationDestino;
var latOrigem  = 0;
var longOrigem = 0;
var latDestino  = 0;
var longDestino = 0;

mygc.geocode({'address' : 'Presidente Vargas 897, Centro RJ'}, function(results, status){
    locationOrigem = results[0].geometry.location;
    latOrigem   = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    longOrigem  = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    mygc.geocode({'address' : 'Abelardo Bueno 3000, Barra da Tijuca RJ'}, function(results, status){
        locationDestino = results[0].geometry.location;
        latDestino  = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        longDestino = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        console.log(locationOrigem);
        console.log(locationDestino);
        console.log(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(locationOrigem, locationDestino));
    });
});
```

Also you need to check status of response. I haven't include because it is not the subject.

Comment: yes i have! But i get this error (firebug): Erro: a is undefined
Arquivo-fonte: http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/pt_br/mapfiles/api-3/5/11/%7Bmain,geometry%7D.js
Linha: 42